# LINQ where clause with an if statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have electrical panel LINQ statement that I want to filter by voltage type.
The condition is if a circuit is 230V it should filter all 400V panels, if its 120V it should filter all 208V panels, all other circuit voltages are equal to the panel voltages. ie 400V = 400V.

I need a conditional statement for my voltage where clause. Here is my first attempt but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
var panels = from p in context.tblPanels
             join x in context.SI_GridCoordinates 
             on new {fac = p.Facility, X = p.X} 
                equals new { fac = x.FAB, X = x.GRID}
             join y in context.SI_GridCoordinates 
             on new { fac = p.Facility, Y = p.Y } 
                equals new { fac = y.FAB, Y = y.GRID }
             where p.Train == item.train &&  
             if (item.voltage == 230) { p.Voltage == 400} else if (item.voltage == 120) { p.Voltage == 208 } else { p.Voltage ==item.voltage}
```

This obviously doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like magic numbers in code, but you can accomplish what you need by using a slightly different approach.

```
if (item.voltage == 230) { p.Voltage == 400} 
else if (item.voltage == 120) { p.Voltage == 208 } 
else { p.Voltage ==item.voltage}
```

becomes

```
((item.voltage == 230 && p.Voltage == 400) || 
(item.voltage == 120 && p.Voltage == 208) || 
(item.voltage != 230 && item.voltage != 120 && p.Voltage ==item.voltage))
```

Comment: Incorrect. In this case, if item.voltage == 230 and p.Voltage == 230 it matches. The OPs example says it should not.

Comment: Magic numbers is referring to hard coded constants. He's saying, does 208 volts mean something special? It's generally better to have named variables, since, if a year from now 208 should really be 209, you just update your single constant definition instead of finding everywhere 208 is found in code.

Comment: @user1781272 - magic numbers are numbers in code that have no meaning to someone unfamiliar with the project. What is 230? What is 400? Why are they being compared?

Answer (score 1):

> The condition is if a circuit is 230V it should filter all 400V panels, if its 120V it should filter all 208V panels, all other circuit voltages are equal to the panel voltages. ie 400V = 400V.

Sounds like [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
where p.Train == item.train &&
    p.Voltage == (item.voltage == 230 ? 400 : item.voltage == 120 ? 208 : item.voltage)
```